# tweetsharp implementation in mvc.net

Tags: tweetsharp

Hi
I want to use Tweetsharp in my mvc.net application to get the list offriends and to share image with them.
But i haven't got the proper documentation and sample for the same. What is need to add in controller action and what in view page.

Please give some links for the same.

Thanks

munish

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MyMethod() {
    TwitterService service = new TwitterService(key, secret, "Token", "Secret");

    ListFriendsOptions options = new ListFriendsOptions();
    options.Cursor = 12345;

    // should the response have user entities
    options.IncludeUserEntities = false;

    // The screen name of the user for whom to return results for.
    options.ScreenName = "";

    options.SkipStatus = false;

    // The ID of the user for whom to return results for.
    options.UserId = 12345;

    // this will return a list of friends for the specified user.
    TwitterCursorList<TwitterUser> listOfFriends = service.ListFriends(options);
}
```

Also note the code above uses a third party library called TweetSharp.

As for the images im not sure as to what to do but you can look at the twitter REST API v1.1 for information

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

TweetSharp
https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about Tweetsharp but take a look at [linq2twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/). It provides easy access to the Twitter API through the use of LINQ.